# Google spreadsheet authorization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Starting to work with Google Spreadsheets (need to get/put some data there)

I have an ASP.NET web-application (MVC), which authenticates the user using google OAuth2. 
That is, the user logs in using google account, and authorizes the application. The application becomes a token in the callback (something like "ya29.bla_bla_bla"). As far as I understand, now it should be possible to use this token to access the spreadsheets.

The OAuth2 request includes the scope "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds".

Now I'm trying to list the sheets (simplest thing I suppose) using the the google [GData Spreadsheets library](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

```
var ss = new SpreadsheetsService("xxx");
ss.SetAuthenticationToken(token);
var q = new SpreadsheetQuery();
var result = ss.Query(q);
```

But this results in 401: Access denied, Invalid token :(

Started the investigation with Fiddler. The following request is sent:

```
GET https: //spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=ya29.bla_bla_bla
```

This results in 401, Access denied, "Invalid token"

But if I do this query "by hand" and use "Bearer ..." instead of "GoogleLogin auth=..." in authorization, like this:

```
GET https: //spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
Authorization: Bearer ya29.bla_bla_bla
```

Then it works, and returns the list of sheets as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the token is not the one I need? Which one do I need then?
Or maybe I should specify a version / scope / whatever somewhere?
What might be the difference between "Authorization: Bearer ..." and "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=..."?

Comment: Your "by hand" version is correct. It looks like a problem that the library you're using hasn't been updated to OAuth 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit, found out that indeed the library used "old" authentication method by default. If you tell it to use Oauth2, then it works :) To do that, one should set the RequestFactory to **GOAuth2RequestFactory**

```
var ss = new SpreadsheetsService("xxx");

var authParams = new OAuth2Parameters
{
    TokenType = "Bearer",
    AccessToken = token,
    ...
};

ss.RequestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("...", "...", authParams);

var q = new SpreadsheetQuery();
var result = ss.Query(q);
```